# Make a scroll function that goes down a set number of times and then back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll

So this should be very simple I guess, but I'm new to this and I got something wrong as the code only runs twice, or scrolls twice instead of whatever number I need and then ends.

`scrNum` is the number that is different every time the script runs on some page and I get it when the page loads, it's usually a small number.

Also is there a simpler way to do this with jQuery maybe?

```
var i = 0;
function scroll(){   

    setTimeout(function(){  

        //scroll to the bottom of page
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);


        //if less than needed execute again
        if( i < scrNum ){
            i++;
            scroll(); 
        } else
            window.scrollTo(0, document.head.scrollHeight);

    }, 2000);

}
```

Comment: well, you said it yourself, `scrNum` equal to a small number (i guess > 0), when you enter the settimeout, you scroll once, then you scroll again because `scrNum > 0`, `scrNum` might be 1, thats why you only run it twice and not more, edit: you can tell us what you actually want to happen so we can help you more.

Comment: The scrNum is usually somewhere from 3-6.I want when a page loads, to scroll to the bottom the number of times that is equal to scrNum, it should scroll every 2 seconds and at the end of that to go back to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work, Please note that there might be a better way to get the positions you want, i just did it for general body tag.

```
var i = 0;

var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < scrNum) { //check if you need to scroll
    $(window).scrollTop($('body').height()); // scroll to the bottom of body ( == the height of body)
    i++; 
  } else {
    $(window).scrollTop($('body').offset().top); //if you did all the scrolls that needed, scroll to the top of body
    clearInterval(myInterval); // IMPORTANT- clear the interval that running.
  }
}, 2000);
```